# CSS to override jquery UI at a specific situation

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui

Can somebody help me override the [jquery UI](http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/#ffDefault=Lucida+Grande,+Lucida+Sans,+Arial,+sans-serif&fwDefault=bold&fsDefault=1.1em&cornerRadius=5px&bgColorHeader=5c9ccc&bgTextureHeader=12_gloss_wave.png&bgImgOpacityHeader=55&borderColorHeader=4297d7&fcHeader=ffffff&iconColorHeader=d8e7f3&bgColorContent=fcfdfd&bgTextureContent=06_inset_hard.png&bgImgOpacityContent=100&borderColorContent=a6c9e2&fcContent=222222&iconColorContent=469bdd&bgColorDefault=dfeffc&bgTextureDefault=02_glass.png&bgImgOpacityDefault=85&borderColorDefault=c5dbec&fcDefault=2e6e9e&iconColorDefault=6da8d5&bgColorHover=d0e5f5&bgTextureHover=02_glass.png&bgImgOpacityHover=75&borderColorHover=79b7e7&fcHover=1d5987&iconColorHover=217bc0&bgColorActive=f5f8f9&bgTextureActive=06_inset_hard.png&bgImgOpacityActive=100&borderColorActive=79b7e7&fcActive=e17009&iconColorActive=f9bd01&bgColorHighlight=fbec88&bgTextureHighlight=01_flat.png&bgImgOpacityHighlight=55&borderColorHighlight=fad42e&fcHighlight=363636&iconColorHighlight=2e83ff&bgColorError=fef1ec&bgTextureError=02_glass.png&bgImgOpacityError=95&borderColorError=cd0a0a&fcError=cd0a0a&iconColorError=cd0a0a&bgColorOverlay=aaaaaa&bgTextureOverlay=01_flat.png&bgImgOpacityOverlay=0&opacityOverlay=30&bgColorShadow=aaaaaa&bgTextureShadow=01_flat.png&bgImgOpacityShadow=0&opacityShadow=30&thicknessShadow=8px&offsetTopShadow=-8px&offsetLeftShadow=-8px&cornerRadiusShadow=8px) css?

I need to get something like below image

[image]

and I got

[image]

If not possible, then probably help me out

1. getting spaces between each panels like in the 1st picture
2. and no border for the panel content as it is in the 1st image.

My Panel (only 1 of them)

```
<div title="Repository Properties" class="class">
    <table style="width:100%; align:left;">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th class="thPanel" align="left">Home</th>
                <td align="left">test</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.thPanel
{
    font-size:11px;
    width:22%;
}
.class
{
    font-size:15px;
    border-style:none;
}
```

Any help would be great! Thanks

**UPDATE**

If I add the below css, it works, but it also affects all the other **ui** stuff on the page, which i don't want, any help?

```
.ui-widget-content{border-style:none;}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding this to your .class style:

```
padding: 10px 0;
```

Comment: Still no luck with the no border thing (panel content)

Comment: Try inspecting the element and seeing which other classes are applied to it.  If there is one more specific to this UI element, try applying border-style: none !important; to that class instead of .ui-widget-content.

Answer (score 2):

```
.thPanel
{
    font-size: 11px !important;
    width:22% !important;
}
.class
{
    font-size:15px !important;
    border-style:none !important;
}
```

This may do the trick. It's the "important directive", and it specifies that the CSS style you are applying has importance over all other CSS styles on that attribute of the element.

Comment: I'm not sure that it's the existing CSS he wanted help with, though I could be wrong. In any event, using !important is almost never needed. Increased specificity and/or just having the "overrides" later in the CSS should be all it takes.